# Microsoft Access - Query - Most Recent Entries

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a main table in Microsoft Access that consists of a document number "AD", a revision number "Rev" and a "Decision Date". There is occasionally more than 1 revision for every AD and 1-2 decision dates for every revision. I want to create a query that selects the most recent entry by decision date, and create a new table that only contains the most recent entries. The purpose of this new table is to have only unique ADs, so that AD can be made a primary key and related to other objects in the database.

```
Current Table: tbl1_Complete_Data  
+----+--------+-----+---------------+  
| ID |   AD   | Rev | Decision Date |  
+----+--------+-----+---------------+  
|  1 |98-24-02|  0  | 1998-06-20    |  
|  2 |98-24-02|  0  | 1998-06-21    |  
|  3 |98-24-02|  1  | 1998-06-24    |  
|  4 |98-24-02|  1  | 1998-06-24    |  
|  5 |98-24-03|  0  | 1998-06-24    |  
|  6 |98-24-03|  0  | 1998-06-24    |  
+----+--------+-----+---------------+  

New Table: tbl2_Report_Data  
+----+--------+-----+---------------+  
| ID |   AD   | Rev | Decision Date |  
+----+--------+-----+---------------+  
|  3 |98-24-02|  1  | 1998-06-24    |  
|  5 |98-24-03|  0  | 1998-06-24    |  
+----+--------+-----+---------------+  
^The goal of this table is to get rid of ID.
```

Comment: [How to ask a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271). Sample data and expected result are the keywords.

Comment: Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question per post. Show what you are able to do.

Comment: This is my first question so I appreciate the feedback. Added expected result and example main table, and edited for clarity.

Comment: If you only want unique AD values, then why are Rev and DecisionDate needed in output? Why eliminate ID?

Comment: Rev and Decision Date are for producing a report; I didnt include fields that werent critical to the question where possible but didnt remove these two fields when copy-pasting from the first table. They are technically unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
SELECT tbl1_Complete_Data.* FROM tbl1_Complete_Data WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM tbl1_Complete_Data AS Dupe 
    WHERE Dupe.AD = tbl1_Complete_Data.AD ORDER BY Dupe.DecisionDate DESC, Dupe.ID);
```

Strongly advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention.

Comment: When I run this code, because multiple decisions can be made on the same day, it doesnt entirely filter out duplicates. Is there a way this code can be edited to only save the first AD? (e.g. by picking the lowest ID value of the duplicates?) The code you wrote includes line 4 and 6 in the example table I made above, but shouldnt. Side note: I looked up naming convention for access objects and renamed my objects, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: See revised answer.